# Kotlin Dagger ViewModel cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to integrate Dagger 2.15 with my Kotlin project. I am getting following compile time exception even I binded ViewModel,

> `error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>    java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends
>    android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be
>    provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

**My Code:**
https://github.com/rramprasad/FoodRecipes

Comment: its issue in Kotlin Dagger processor 
you should convert yours ViewModelFactory and ViewModelKey into Java because its working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have gone through your code and I believe problem lies somewhere in this code:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindMainViewModel(userViewModel: MainViewModel): MainViewModel
```

For binding MainViewModel, first of all here you need to do constructor injection in MainViewModel which would be like:

```
class MainViewModel
@Inject constructor()
: AndroidViewModel(Application())
```

Also the way you are binding or using @Binds with your MainViewModel is not correct you cannot return what you are passing in as argument, dagger will throw **Cyclic Dependency** exception at build time. For more information about Binds refer to this [article](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Binds.html) and to avoid this error, change your binds code to this:

```
 @Binds
 @IntoMap
 @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
 abstract fun bindMainViewModel(userViewModel: MainViewModel): ViewModel
```

Try these changes and let me know if you face any issue. Thanks

Comment: This issue fixed by adding JvmSuppressWildcards in constructor second parameter of class ViewModelFactory. It works fine.But Provides methods works only on AppModule. If I add another sub module with ContributesAndroidInjector it does not works.Shows error message error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.lang.String> cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or from an Provides-annotated method.

Comment: @Ramprasad if you can share the link of your code where you are adding another sub module along with ContributesAndroidInjector which is creating issue, then it would be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: https://github.com/rramprasad/FoodRecipes/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rramprasad/foodrecipes/dependencyinjection/FoodRecipesAppModule.kt

Comment: its issue in Kotlin Dagger processor 
you should convert yours ViewModelFactory and ViewModelKey into Java because its working for me

Comment: The person implemented that in kotlin, why to convert it in Java? Moreover issue was not in processor, it was in wrong implementation of `@Binds` annotation, refer this [link](https://dagger.dev/tutorial/04-depending-on-interface) for more detatils.